# Interfacing PHP with Lucene without changing anything

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I am building a search engine. In this regard, I have built a Lucene indexer in Java and also built a web interface in PHP where the user will submit the query. As my search is geo-temporal specific, so by PHP I have tracked the user's current time and location along with the query. Now my question is how will I pass those values from PHP to Lucene search module that is in Java.

In this context I have studied Zend. But it seems that in Zend I have to rewrite the searcher and indexer in Zend Lucene framework that is different from Java Lucene that I have used. I am asking is there any way that I can use to integrate my PHP web interface with Lucene without changing anything to underlying indexer and searcher that I have written in Java Lucene.

So in brief, I want to know how to pass those PHP variables to the underlying Lucene searcher in Java and display the output of the searcher back in PHP web interface. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand Zend Search, it is an implementation of Lucene for PHP (Lucene 2.3 in Zend 1 -- don't know which Lucene version for Zend 2). The API is not a straight port, but you can use Zend Search with vanilla Lucene indexes. Google for "Zend 2 search lucene compatibility".

Answer (score 0):

The Zend_Search_Lucene and related classes that were in Zend Framework 1, which are a standalone Lucene implementation and don't depend on any other libraries, have been replaced with ZendSearch, now a [git repository](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSearch). However, the repository doesn't contain any documentation. I assume the Zend Framework 1 documentation for **Zend_Search_Lucene** applies equally to ZendSearch: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html. I don't know why ZendSearch is not part of Zend Framework 2.